# Facebook: how to integrate app icon in a page?

Tags: facebook

In the following screenshot I've borded the various apps, integrated in the facebook page, in red. How do you do something similar?

I think facebook calls them "pagelet_timeline_app_nav_app"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app has to be yours to define the default image or you have to be the page admin to change it on your page. I pointed out the places where you can change the settings.

(The screenshots are in german language but i think you should be able to figure it out anyway, i marked the relevant places.)

**App settings:**

[image]

**Pagetab settings:**

[image]

**Change image of pagetab:**

[image]